# Postgres - edit currently running query

Tags: postgresql, optimization

is it possible in postgresql to edit the currently running query. Or killing the query and firing another one in its place.

I have a problem with an updater of one program. One query created by the producer is badly optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify a currently running query, but you can kill it. In the session that started the query, you can send a cancel request. From another database session, you can query the view `pg_stat_activity` to find the `pid` (process ID) of the database backend that runs the offending query. Then, using the number obtained, you can interrupt the query with

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(12345);
```

Note that you need to be the same database user as the running query to see the entry in `pg_stat_activity` or cancel the query. Alternatively, you need to be a database user with high permissions (superuser or a member of `pg_read_all_stats` and `pg_signal_backend`).

The best you can do is to prevent the problem from happening in the first place by setting the `statement_timeout` parameter. Then queries that run longer than that limit will be canceled automatically.